# How to set % height in fluid layout?

Tags: iphone, html, css, responsive-design

I am designing fluid layout pages (defining everything in % in CSS) for multiple devices (desktop/tablet/mobile)

Now while I do understand that giving width:100% takes the entire viewport available width (i.e. available browser area) and accordingly calculates all the % widths ?

But my question is how do I set or convert any "pixel" height to % height for defining fluid layouts CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give your body styles like so...

```
 body {width: 100%; height: 100%; min-height: 100%; height: auto;}
```

As your body has a height of the viewport, anything that is a child of it can be specified using percentage, like a div 50% of the screen would be...

```
body div {height: 50%; min-height: 50%; height: auto;}
```

Remember % is inherited from its parent.

Comment: Ok..so when we give body 100% height, how does it render on mobile device..like is the % calculated based on device viewport or the visual viewport ? Also why do we need to also specify the other 2 attributes for height?

Comment: The other 2 attribrutes ensure it works on older browsers, in newer browsers you only need to specify the width and height. And for mobile devices I am not sure but I would guess it would be the visual viewport as if a browser is resized on a laptop (ie the visual viewport) then so do the other elements retrospectively.

Comment: Hmm..right..thats what i am just wondering...if height:100% works as expected on mobile browsers...like how width works ...

Comment: I just tried setting the height based on what you gave and it is not working...it just takes the height as per the content...ignores the % height

Comment: Also when you say you have used min-height: 50%; height: auto; for older browsers , could you please confirm if you are referring to IE6/7 and others..Please confirm, as I am mainly testing on newere desktop browsers and iPhone/iPad..